# Can I get all the values from XML types using SAX parser.schema?

Tags: xml, parsing, schema, lexical

I have an XML doc that has different values, for example, `MATH101`. Also, there is `QName` that gives the range/type of the valid books, for example, `bo:books` or `xs:strings`.

So, is there a way that helps to get all the values from any type in XSD with knowing the types?

Comment: So what is `MATH01`, an element or attribute name? You might want to show a minimal schema and/or XML instance document and then show us for those samples which values you want as the result.

Comment: for example <book name="MATH101"  range="math:books">  <book name="Physics101"  range="physics:books">  I have the math.xsd and physics.xsd but my goal here is to get all the math books and the physics books and all the values of any types in  .xsd .. in order to manipulate the values ..

Comment: The idea here I am looking for a method that the input is (value, types' name, file.xsd) the outPut is all the values in this type.For example integer min=1 and max=10 the outPut should be (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)